# Source Not Found main.xml Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Im a beginner to android developing and have run into a problem. Im making a simple app that displays presidents in a List View. But when I try to run it on the emulator, ir gets this error: Source not Found net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample.ListFragmentExampleActivity. Here is my code for the java file:

```
package net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment {
String[] presidents = {
        "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
        "John F. Kennedy",
        "Lyndon B. Johnson",
        "Richard Nixon",
        "Gerald Ford",
        "Jimmy Carter",
        "Ronald Reagen",
        "George H. W. Bush",
        "Bill Clinton",
        "George W. Bush",
        "Barack Obama"
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
}
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, presidents));
    }
        public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
                int position, long id)
        {   
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "You have selected item : " + presidents[position],
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="net.learn2develop.ListFragmentExample.Fragment1"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name="net.learn2develop.ListFragmentExample.Fragment1"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code for fragment1.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Logcat trace:

```
[2013-04-25 18:31:55 - ListFragmentExample] Android Launch!
[2013-04-25 18:31:55 - ListFragmentExample] adb is running normally.
[2013-04-25 18:31:55 - ListFragmentExample] Performing           net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample.ListFragmentExampleActivity activity launch
[2013-04-25 18:31:55 - ListFragmentExample] Automatic Target Mode: using existing  emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Android_4.0'
[2013-04-25 18:31:55 - ListFragmentExample] Uploading ListFragmentExample.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-04-25 18:31:56 - ListFragmentExample] Installing ListFragmentExample.apk...
[2013-04-25 18:32:03 - ListFragmentExample] Success!
[2013-04-25 18:32:03 - ListFragmentExample] Starting activity net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample.ListFragmentExampleActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-04-25 18:32:05 - ListFragmentExample] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample/.ListFragmentExampleActivity }
[2013-04-25 18:32:06 - ListFragmentExample] Attempting to connect debugger to 'net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample' on port 8666
```

Here is my Manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample.ListFragmentExampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone fill me in here? I dont know what im doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you post more of your logcat trace?

Comment: ummm. its to long. how many lines do you need of it?

Comment: Edit your question and post it there. Maybe first 10~20 lines or so. just want to see the call back trace

Comment: No. the other one is logcat, not console. However, it seems you should check your `manifest.xml` to see what your main activity is.

Comment: oh. sorry. It doesn't appear that I can copy logcat though.

Comment: Check your `AndroidManifest.xml`. The console says ActivityManager is trying to load `ListFragmentExampleActivity` to start your app. Check if you have the correct activity.

Comment: Ok. Its supposed to start up Fragment1 activity but how do I change it to work with what I want it to? (sorry. I am so new to android im actually going through an android book to teach me how and this problem is in one of the try it outs you do.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28925/discussion-between-caden-ratcliff-and-stonebird)

Comment: Hi stonebird! Um. Can you possibly come back to stack tommorrow around 6 or 7? That would be great. Im putting my Manifest file code in the answer for you if you want to look over it. Again, thanks so much for all your time.

Comment: @CadenRatcliff, After reading your chat, I've updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your code, I changed every "Listfragmentexample" to "ListFragmentExample". This happens in multiple files.

The name "ListFragmentExample" represents your package name and needs to be consistent across your project files. If you want it to be "Listfragmentexample" then it needs to be like that **everywhere** in your project when you want to refer to something in your package, since that is the package name. No mix and match should be allowed.

I've tested it and it works on my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `@android:id/list` instead of `@id/android:list`

Also, I'd write `listfragmentexample` instead of `Listfragmentexample` and instead of `ListFragmentExample`. Your capitalization of that package name really wasn't consistent between your main.xml file and your manifest file. Besides, personally, I wouldn't even capitalize that word at all.

This should take care of your error.

But personally, I'd also write `".ListFragmentExampleActivity"` instead of `"net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample.ListFragmentExampleActivity"` just to simplify the manifest. It really didn't need to be that complicated. And this last change I'm suggesting won't fix anything, it just makes the manifest more readable.

**Update:**

From your chat, it does seem that Stonebird picked up on the inconsistent capitalization of the package name reference, it's just that this inconsistent capitalization needs to be corrected in more than just the manifest activity android:name.

In the manifest activity android:name, please just do what I suggested above. Write `".ListFragmentExampleActivity"` instead of `"net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample.ListFragmentExampleActivity"`

Then within the project explorer pane of Eclipse, place your mouse on the package name, right-click and select:

`Refactor > Rename` to `"net.learn2develop.listfragmentexample"` instead of `"net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample"` Make sure to check the checkbox that says Update all references and to preview your changes (don't worry about the errors you're getting after that, there still needs some work left to do). And if it asks you to update configuration launch files, accept that as well. Turning all your package names to lower case (except for the ClassName part) is a good habit to have in Java, because then you don't need to start remembering what particular case you used on what.

After that, on the second or third line of your manifest, make sure to write `"net.learn2develop.listfragmentexample"` instead of `"net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample"` (I don't think that the Eclipse Refactor command took care of that one).

Then in your main.xml, write 
`"net.learn2develop.listfragmentexample.Fragment1"` instead of  `"net.learn2develop.ListFragmentExample.Fragment1"` 
and write `"net.learn2develop.listfragmentexample.Fragment2"` instead of `"net.learn2develop.ListFragmentExample.Fragment2"` (normally, Eclipse Refactor takes care of renaming those attributes, but it didn't in this case because the capitalization mistake in this case is not even consistent with your first capitalization mistake, so it wouldn't pick up on that when doing its search and replace)

And finally, in **all** your java files, make sure that it's written:

`package net.learn2develop.listfragmentexample;` instead of

`package net.learn2develop.Listfragmentexample;` (this part should have been taken care by Eclipse, but this is something you should double-check just in case).

After that, do a Ctrl-shift-o within each java file (to organize the imports). If you did that step too early before you properly reset the package name, then it will have imported android.R (which is **NOT** what you want). Make sure that `import android.R;` does **not** appear anywhere in your java files. If it's there, delete that line, and do a Ctrl-shift-o (to organize imports) until your own R is imported and **not** the android.R

After that, with your mouse select `Project > Clean...` or `Source > Clean...` (I forget which menu). And if Eclipse errors, open the Eclipse Error View Pane to make sure you didn't miss any other places where the previous package names needed to be changed. From the Error View pane, you can double-click on each error in question to take you to the spot where Eclipse thinks the mistake is located.

Comment: Thank you so much stonefish and Stephan! That was thwarting me for a while. And thanks for all the time you spent helping me to!